# How to subtract resulting value from two different Futures?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firebase and Flutter I'm trying to calculate a count of unread messages.   I have the chat function working well, and using a visibility widget I am logging the userID to an array on the message if they've seen it.

The challenge now is to simply query the number of messages that the user hasn't read.    I am attempting to do this by querying the number of messages they have read (since there is not an array-does-not-contain), and then subtract that from the total number of messages.   But I can't help but wonder if I'm missing a design pattern here.  Any help is appreciated.

```
child: Text((Provider.of<PerformingArtsCenterState>(context,
            listen: false)
        .selectedPACRef!
        .collection("chat_messages")
        .where("performanceID",
            isEqualTo: widget.performance.id)
        .where("readByUsers",
            arrayContains: Provider.of<LoginState>(
                    context,
                    listen: false)
                .user!
                .userID)
        .snapshots()
        .length -
    Provider.of<PerformingArtsCenterState>(context,
            listen: false)
        .selectedPACRef!
        .collection("chat_messages")
        .where("performanceID",
            isEqualTo: widget.performance.id)
        .snapshots()
        .length)
.toString())
```

I have tried a few different patterns that seem to work, including using two separate FutureBuilders to update two different int variables on the widget.   It just seems that there is a better design than the extra 50 lines or so needed to write two FutureBuilders to just get two integer values.

Answer (score 0):

Your chat model should have a boolean `read` or `isRead` or whatever name you like then update that to `true` if the other user entered the chatRoom.

```html
 class Chat{
 final String content;
 final bool isRead;   //add this to your model
 }
```

this make it easier to query all the chats `where('isRead', isEqualto, false)`